# Qlik sense API integration in android application

Tags: android, qliksense

I want to integrate the Qlik sense API on android.So i want to know that is there any way to integrate Qlik sense on native application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the application is developed in xamarin c# then you can Qlik sense SDK

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/QlikSense.NetSDK/

otherwise use Qlik Sense Repository Service API

> http://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/1.0/Subsystems/Qlik_Sense_Repository_Service_API/Content/QRS%20API/Repository_Introduction.htm

Comment: Thanks ldriss for response,So it will work on android native app.Do you have any demo api for this.

Comment: You welcome, there is a lot of exemples here for QS API and also for SDK .NET ==>  https://github.com/stefanwalther/awesome-qap